# Choke on the bitter fruit of my demise

Tags: science-based, creature-design, anatomy, reproduction, sex

In death a new beginning is certain, for the jaws that bit my flesh will suffer a tragic end and no amount of laments or tears will ease the pain.

My blood will flower and fruit inside their bodies, growing a new me inside of them.

My killer, who violated my body and soul will also be  the nest of my children, so they my avenge me as they ironically burst out leaving a carcass of what was once my violator.

I can also reproduce sexually if my social fitness allows and if the opportunity arises, yet my blood is capable of producing new offsprings when I'm being eaten by another creature. How is this possible?

Comment: Why are there both #sex and #reproduction tags?

Comment: Not all reproduction involves a sex act, as exemplified by a question very nearby.

Comment: Ironic isn't it? By asking the very query you asked, you actually answered the question you asked in comments!

Answer (score 11):

Within your bloodstream flow several thousand dormant pluripotent pseudo-morulas. They can't stay dormant forever, of course, but the original produces more periodically as the older ones perish. Low-doses of some suppressant hormone keeps them in check.

However, when eaten by some wild animal, your flesh is present within their mouths, where any number of ulcers and lacerations are present... enough for one of these to enter their bloodstream. These migrate to some part of the body (abdomen, most likely) where it uses that same blood vessel to supply itself with nutrients.

In addition to using the same tricks that most parasites use to trick the host immune system, it also induces various pregnancy-like hormones to cause the host body to be a more amenable environment. Unlike pregnancy though, the developing clone doesn't gestate in a way that will preserve the viability of the host... in fact, since this organism is a confirmed predator of the species, if the gestation kills the host that's just good strategy. The host eventually withers away, unable to move, hunt, or care for itself... just about the time the clone is ready for rebirth.

Comment: Voted up ! nice solution ! On the sideline, would it become possible, with these "pseudo-morulas" parasites getting more active when the host is aging, an elderly host could stop taking the hormone and give birth to himself and in effect become immortal as a result ?

Comment: The original could certainly do that, though I was imagining this being less of a conscious thing than perhaps you're going for. Just remember that the clones are only clones, and won't be born with the memories/personality/whatever of the original (unless you're positing some alien biology unlike our own). There'd need to be a mechanism by which one of the pseudo-morulas suppresses the development of the others, but that's rather trivial I think.

Comment: The act of death itself could trigger the event. Stress hormones, for instance, triggered by the imminent death of the spawner. The "pluripotent pseudo-morulas" could be well on the way to becoming embryos even before they enter the new host's body.

Answer (score 1):

Covid has made the knowledge about RNA viruses prolific.

So far, however, the viral mRNA process seems only to spur the host infected cell to make copies of just the virus proteins itself, or of specific proteins. They are single-strand RNA.

Should a 'virus' system evolve such that the entire genome of the original creature be encapsulated in a multi-strand RNA virus package, this virus could conjecturally result in the virus causing the infected host cells to produce entire stem cells. These stem cells would then be fully functioning 'clone' cells that would grow in the petri dish of the new host, surrounded by nutrients, resulting in clones of the original creature.

The cells of the original creature, of course, would have evolved defence mechanisms that prevent the viral RNA from hijacking the cells in their own body.

Comment: An interesting conjecture, could the virus inject its own RNA into the cell, eventually replacing the cell DNA, and causing the cell to 'transform' into the original creature? Like injecting a new nucleus into the cell, the way Dolly was cloned? That is, the new creature is not reproduced in the host body, the host body is transformed into the creature, cell by cell?